# Admin Site shows the timezone wrong

Tags: django, timezone

Trying my hands on Django. `TIME_ZONE`at admin module shows different than the local time. I would like to edit the time according to the current time. Which Django file should I edit to synchronize the time?

I tried the documentation on official Django website but did not help me out.[image]

````
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `settings.py`, add a `TIME_ZONE` config:

E.G:

```
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
```

or

```
TIME_ZONE = "America/Boise"
```

Plus, enable `USE_TZ`:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)

Comment: @Startgazer: thanks. My settings.py already has the setting which you are suggesting.

Comment: Oh sorry, that image did not load when I saw it the first time.

Is UTC your local time?

Comment: its okay. no, I am in India currently. But next week I will be in Germany.

Comment: You can use `TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Calcutta"` [see here the available tzs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: oh wow! it worked magically. Thanks a lot. Please give a thumbs up on my question for my extrinsic motivation from this website! Thank you.  @Stargazer

Comment: Glad to hear it